# OAuth2 Discord with Spring Security don't have to login everyti

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am looking for someone to help me with my Spring Boot Security configuration. Here is my issue:

1. The authentication system work with OAuth2 client (Discord one only)
2. Everything works fine but when I close my browser I have to re-login again which is painful. I would like my application to save the authorization so the user only log again when needed.
3. I am not very experienced with Web & Spring stuff yet, should I enable csrf in my case?
4. Spring boot: `2.7.13-SNAPSHOT`.

Here is my code:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/dashboard/**")
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()

                .logout()
                    .disable()

                // TODO: 02/07/2023 not sure?
                //.csrf(c -> c.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))

                .oauth2Login()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                    .loginPage("/login/oauth2")
                    .failureUrl("/login/oauth2?failed=true")
                    .userInfoEndpoint().userService(this.userService());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> userService() {
        return new CustomOAuth2UserService(this.restOperations());
    }

    @Bean
    public RestOperations restOperations() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

Sorry to take your time but I could not find a proper documentation about this!

Comment: Whether you need to log back in would probably be a session issue, not an oauth2 issue. Do you get a session cookie and is it persisted after you close your browser and reopen it and open the site?

Comment: I have a cookie session "JSESSIONID" when I log in but when I close my browser (not just the site, the whole browser) it disappear, how can I make so it is gonna be saved?

Comment: Maybe the cookie doesn't have an expiration date? I think that means it would be cleared when the browser exits. Or it could be a browser setting. I'm no cookie expert either.